# Rename files in different subfolders

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I would like to rename multiple files that are located in different folders. More specifically, I would like to add zeroes to the middle of the filename, so that all filenames have three digits (and therefore show up in a logical order).

To be more specific, I have 130+ folders with 400+ .nii files in each folder. Each .nii file has the following pattern:

> swu_run1_P_139_Vol_1.nii

- P_### ranges from P76 to P277 (participant number)
- Vol_### ranges from 1 till 405 (volume number)

As the volume ranges from 1 till 405, it means that any list starts with 100, rather than going 1-405 (e.g. it starts: 100 - 101 - 102 [..] - 109 - **10** - 110 - 111 etc). One way to solve this, is to add zeroes to the filename and make everything three digits, e.g:

```
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.nii -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_001.nii
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_2.nii -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_002.nii
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_10.nii -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_010.nii
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_120.nii -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_120.nii
```

I have little experience with unix/linux systems, but using previous threads, I managed to come up with the following code. It has two parts to it:

**1. Rename multiple filesnames, adding zeroes to the middle of the filename:**

```
rename Vol_ Vol_0 *Vol_[0-9].nii
```

If I run this in a subfolder, I get the following error message:

```
Error: rename: swu_run1_P_275_Vol_1.nii: rename to swu_run1_P_275_Vol_01.nii failed: No such file or directory
```

Strangely enough, it is adding the zero to Vol_1-9. However, it does not add a zero to any number which already has two or three digits:

```
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.txt -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_01.nii
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_10.txt -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_10.nii
swu_run1_P_277_Vol_100.txt -> swu_run1_P_277_Vol_100.nii
```

*It seems like there is some kind of weird loop going on with the expression (it tries to change the new Vol_01, giving the error message)? And why is it not adding an zero to the two/three digits?*

**2. Find all `.nii` files in the relevant subfolders, and then do a batch renaming:**

```
find . -iname "*.nii" -execdir rename Vol_ Vol_0 *Vol_[0-9].nii '{}' \;
```

My understanding of this code is as follows:

- `find . -iname "*.nii"` searches for all .nii files, both in the current folder and the subfolders
- `-execdir` tells it to apply the following expression to the current folder and the subfolders, i.e. adding a zero
- `rename Vol_ Vol_0 *Vol_[0-9].nii` adds that zero (using the format of *fromtext* *totext* *filelist*)
- `'{}'` is there for the path name of the file
- `\;` is there to end the -execdir expression

If I try to run the code on more folders, I get the following error message:

```
Error: rename: *Vol_[0-9].nii: rename to *Vol_0[0-9].nii failed: No such file or directory
```

I think that I am getting the error message because the -execdir is not being executed in the subfolders, but I can't work out how to solve this.

*I would rather not go into each subfolder manually to run the shell, so do you have any suggestions how to improve this code (and make it work)? And why am I getting the error message of "No such file or directory"?*

Comment: Are the `.txt` filename suffixes a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's a typo: everything should be listed as .nii (there is no `.txt`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we had the name `swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.nii` in the variable `name`, then `${name##*_}` would be `1.nii` (the longest prefix string matching `*_` is removed).

Taking that and removing `.nii` leaves us with the number that we want to zero-fill to three character's width:

```
name=swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.nii

number=${name##*_}
number=${number%.nii}
```

In the `bash` shell, the easiest way (possibly) to zero-fill the number is with `printf`:

```
printf '%.3d' "$number"    # would print 001 (with no newline)
```

We can construct the new name at the same time:

```
printf '%s_%.3d.nii' "${name%_*.nii}" "$number"
```

That `printf` command would print `swu_run1_P_277_Vol_001.nii` by removing the suffix string that matches `_*.nii` from the original name, adding `_` and the zero-filled number, and then the `.nii` suffix string.

To top this off, we may print the resulting string *directly* into a new variable with `printf -v newname ...`.

Putting this together for a single name:

```
name=swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.nii

number=${name##*_}
number=${number%.nii}

printf -v newname '%s_%.3d.nii' "${name%_*.nii}" "$number"
```

Then it's just a matter of `mv "$name" "$newname"`.

Ok, so how to do it for all relevant files?

Let's assume that all relevant files matches the globbing pattern `*Vol_*.nii`, then, with `find`,

```
find . -type f -name '*Vol_*.nii' -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        dirpath=${pathname%/*}  # or: dirpath=$(dirname "$pathname")
        name=${pathname##*/}    # or: name=$(basename "$pathname")

        number=${name##*_}
        number=${number%.nii}

        printf -v newname "%s_%.3d.nii" "${name%_*.nii}" "$number"

        printf "Would rename %s --> %s\n" "$pathname" "$dirpath/$newname"
        # mv "$pathname" "$dirpath/$newname"
    done' bash {} +
```

The inline `bash -c` script here gets called by `find` with batches of found pathnames that fulfill the `-type f` (is a regular file) and `-name` (has a particular name) criteria.  The script loops over these pathnames and pulls out the filename into `name` and the directory pathname into `dirpath`.

It then does the same operations as we did before to arrive at a new name, which gets stored in `newname`, and then it renames the file.

Well, I've commented out the actual `mv` command for safety.  You should run this once an see that the output is correct first.  If you use GNU tools, you may also want to use `mv -b` to make backups of files if there are name collisions.

---

As a side note, in the `zsh` shell, the globbing pattern

```
./**/*Vol_*.nii(n)
```

would expand to all those names *in numerical order* (and recursively down int subdirectories):

```
$ print -rC1 ./**/*Vol_*.nii(n)
./swu_run1_P_277_Vol_1.nii
./swu_run1_P_277_Vol_2.nii
./swu_run1_P_277_Vol_10.nii
./swu_run1_P_277_Vol_120.nii
```

Comment: Amazing, it seems to work like a charm (and thanks for the clear explanations)! I have one question, if you don't mind? If I were to want to zero-fill with 4 digits, would I then change `%s_%.3d.nii` to `%s_%.4d.nii`? Does it work like that?

Comment: @fidodido Correct. But run with the `mv` commented out first so that you see that it would work.

Comment: @Kusalananda where does the second 'bash' in `... -exec bash -c '...' bash {} +` come from? `man find` only mentions '-exec command {} +' whereby I guess 'command' would only be 'bash -c '...'  What am I missing??

Comment: @bey0nd The second `bash` is an argument, a string that will go into `$0` within the in-line script. `$0` in not part of the positional parameters, and will not be part of the loop. It will be used by the `bash -c` script if it needs to generate any diagnostic messages (error messages). It's an arbitrary string, but it makes sense to use `bash`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks a lot for the feetback. I missed the fact with $0.